# I'm unable to switch windows by name (driver.switchTo("windowName"))

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a test and I'm finding that I'm unable to switch to a particular window by name. At this point in the test there are three windows open and the only unusual thing about the name of the window that I want to switch to is that it contains a hyphen. I'm able to switch to it using the below work-around (using window handle rather than name) but I would rather use the name. Does anybody know why I cannot?

```
Set <String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String i : handles) {
            waitForWindowAndSwitchToIt(i); //this function is basically a wrapper for switchTo() - the problem is not here
            if (driver.getTitle().equals("My website - test")) { 
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the output on driver.getTitle() ?

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver doesn't have a .switchTo method that takes a "title" argument.  You would have to override and provide your own overloaded method if you wanted to do something like that.  Personally, I think using window handles is more elegant because they are unique whereas a title has no guarantee to be unique.